# grep: не работает регулярка

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

Вот часть текста:

[image: картинка]

Мне нужно вывести только эти хэши. Использую команду:

```
grep "([\d\w]{32})" data.txt
```

И ничего не выводит!

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `grep -oP '\w{32}' data.txt`

Comment: Зачем тут `grep`?

Comment: > `grep -oP '\w{32}' data.txt` - добавить параметр `w` и готово

Comment: Я таки извиняюсь, но grep вам принципиален? Судя по показанным данным вам просто нужно второе поле: `cat data.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Answer (score 1):

Внутри квадратных скобок обратный слеш [является обычным символом](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). Т. е. ваше регулярное выражение примет символы `\`, `d` или `w`.

К тому же, вы должны сказать `grep`, что ваша строка паттернов является регулярным выражением с помощью [флагов](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) `-G`, `-P` или `-E`.

---

Резюмируя, можете использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
grep -E "[[:alnum:]]{32}"
```