# Как в grep найти любое количество любых символов?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

в обычной регулярке выражение `[\s\S]*` находит любые пробельные и непробельные символы, но в grep [не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253194/grep-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) слеши в квадратных скобках

Comment: чем .* не устраивает?

Comment: он до конца строки только действует, если есть символ переноса он останавливается на нём

Comment: приведите пример где и что не работает. grep "[\s\S]*" file вполне себе все содержимое выводит

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev вот пример, на сайте работает, а в грепе нет https://regex101.com/r/nrqbPP/1  сама команда grep -a -P "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd[\s\S]*?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /home/user1/test1.txt или вместо параметра -P можно -E

Answer (score 0):

> он до конца строки только действует, если есть символ переноса он
> останавливается на нём

тогда просто *отмените* переносы

**man grep**

```
-z, --null-data
    Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte 
(the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this 
option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```

Comment: не помогло, 
grep -a -z -P "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /home/user1/test1.txt вообще ничего не находит в примере текста (через файл грепал) https://regex101.com/r/nrqbPP/1